# Constant definition in Clojure

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm trying to define a macro for defining compile-time constants syntax for which was added in Clojure 1.3:

> == 2.14 ^:const defs ==
>
> ^:const lets you name primitive values with speedier reference.
>
> (def constants {:pi 3.14 :e 2.71})
>
> (def ^:const pi (:pi constants)) (def ^:const e (:e constants))
>
> The overhead of looking up :e and :pi in the map happens at compile
>   time, as (:pi constants) and (:e constants) are evaluated when their
>   parent def forms are evaluated.

Basically I want some syntax sugar around `(def ^:const ... ...)`, so I'm trying to do it like this:

```
(defmacro defconst [const-name const-val]
  `(def ^:const ~const-name ~const-val))
```

But this doesn't work:

```
user=> (macroexpand '(defconst pi 3.14))
(def pi 3.14)
```

From what I gather the `#^<...>` meta shortcut is a reader macro, and to define a macro that adds some metadata to something, one should use `(with-meta ...)`.

I haven't found any documentation regarding `^:const`. Does this syntactical construct even create some sort of metadata? Following example doesn't show any:

```
user=> (def ^:const pi 3.14)
#'user/pi
user=> (meta pi)
nil
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first issue is that you are examining the metadata of `3.14`.  Use `(meta (var pi))` to see the metadata of `pi`.  If you do, you will see that it includes `:const true`.

```
(defmacro defconst [const-name const-val]
  `(def
    ~(with-meta const-name
       (assoc (meta const-name) :const true))
    ~const-val))
```

accurately reproduces the metadata and performance of `^:const` (the code is adapted from the source of `defn-`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked by doing `(time (dotimes [_ 1e10] (* pi pi)))` vs `(time (dotimes [_ 1e10] (* 3.14 3.14)))` and it amounts to the same execution time.

Comment: Interesting.  I missed the point of `const` -- I didn't catch that `const` "vars" have more efficient lookup.  They make much more sense, now.